# Can regex do this faster?

Tags: php, regex

I want to capitalise each word and combine it into 1 word, e.g:

> home = Home
>   about-us = AboutUs

Here is the function I use at the moment, can regex do this better or more efficient?

```
public function formatClassName($name)
{
 $name = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);
 $name = ucwords($name);
 $name = str_replace(' ', '', $name);
 return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think a regex can capitalize the words, so you'd still have to have two separate regexes, and I think with such simple cases, regular expressions are overkill (think hunting squirrels with artillery). This code is simple, clear and easy to understand. DON'T TOUCH IT!

Comment: RegEx can capitalize the first letter, but your advice is dead on, KISS.

Comment: Obviously, you've never hunted squirrels with artillery ;)

Comment: You can capitalize word with `preg` since you can pass the `/e` flag and put PHP code as the "replacement".

Comment: @KennyTM: I hadn't thought of that, but having a regular expression processor call a piece of external custom code seems like cheating somehow.

Answer (score 12):

With regex, you'd probably have to use something "complex", like [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) *(to be able to apply the `strtoupper` or `ucwords` function)*, which would make your code at least harder to understand -- and possibly slower, but the most important thing is that your code is easy to understand.

Considering **your solution just works and is simple and easy**, I would probably keep it, if I were in your place.

Answer (score 4):

This code works:

```
$in = Array("home", "about-us");
foreach ($in as $a) {

  ## this is the line you're looking for
  $out = preg_replace('/-?\b(.)/e', "strtoupper('$1')", $a);

  echo "$a  = $out<br/>";
}
```

But I doubt it's faster, and I agree with the other commenters that it's not necessarily better.  Decreasing three lines to one hairy regexp is only good if you're [golfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Perl_golf).